# Trying to map lat/long coords, can't input the required arguments

Tags: python, list, function, google-maps, pygmaps

I have a function [(mymap.addpoint from pygmaps module)](https://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/) that requires 2 float arguments. I have a for loop that generates the latitude and longitude for each city in a list. I want to use these coordinates to add multiple points(markers or pins) to a google map but I can't figure out how to input them as arguments. map_regions is a list of cities:

```
print map_regions
for item in map_regions:
        try:
            geo = Geocoder.geocode(item)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            point = (geo[0].coordinates)
        print point
regions_map.addpoint(lat, long)
```

I realize the above code doesn't include the addpoint function in the for loop. I'm still trying to figure out how to pass the 2 arguments just once in the function, before doing it multiple times, if that makes any sense.

This doesn't work because two args are required:

```
regions_map.addpoint(point)
```

I tried this but it seems the 2 arguments are being seen as strings not floats:

```
for item in map_regions:
        try:
            geo = Geocoder.geocode(item)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            point = (geo[0].coordinates)
            joint = ', '.join(map(str, point))
            split_point = joint.split(',', 2)
            lat = split_point[0]
            lon = split_point[1]
        print point
regions_map.addpoint(lat, long)
```

This is the error I get:

> ['MI', 'Allegan, MI', 'Alma, MI (All Digital)', 'Almont Township, MI', 'Alpena, MI', >'Arnold Lake/Hayes, MI (All Digital)', 'Au Gres, MI']
>
> (44.3148443, -85.60236429999999)
>
> (42.5291989, -85.8553031)
>
> (43.3789199, -84.6597274)
>
> (42.9450131, -83.05761559999999)
>
> (45.0616794, -83.4327528)
>
> (45.0616794, -83.4327528)
>
> (44.0486294, -83.6958161)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/digital1/Dropbox/Programming/Map_Locations/gmaps.py", line 82, in 
>      gmaps_mapit()
>
> File "/Users/digital1/Dropbox/Programming/Map_Locations/gmaps.py", line 78, in >gmaps_mapit
>      regions_map.draw('./mymap.html')
>
> File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pygmaps.py", line 48, in draw
>
> File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pygmaps.py", line 83, in drawpoints
>
> File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pygmaps.py", line 129, in drawpoint
>
> TypeError: float argument required, not str

How can I pass the coordinates as arguments for the function using a for loop (or whatever) to generate multiple points?

I'm a pretty good googler but this one is tough. I'm not even sure how to search for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says `addpoint()` function needs parameters as float, you are passing them as string. All you need is to parse them as float:

```
regions_map.addpoint(float(lat), float(long))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I was banging my head against the wall trying to make this harder than it was.